# Java VisualVM 1.3.9 incorrect plugin url

Tags: java, visualvm

I tried to install memory pool plugin but it is pointing to incorrect location 
https://java.net/downloads/memorypoolview/com-kodewerk-visualvm-memorypoolsb4.nbm. How do I install memory pool plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from URL this plugin is not developed by VisualVM devs. It was a separate project at java.net. Unfortunately java.net was discontinued and the author of the memory pool plugin did not set up new project yet. There is already a discussion about the memory pool plugin at [new visualvm home at github](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues/25).